# Are there mappings between WordNet 3.1 and WordNet 3.0 synsetId?

Tags: wordnet

I am trying to map a Wordnet 3.0 synset to Wordnet 3.1
For example: purl.org/vocabularies/princeton/wn30/synset-embrace-verb-2

I see that in Wordnet 3.1 there is a owl:sameAs statement for
 http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn31/201427110-v
owl:sameAs http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/instances/synset-embrace-verb-2

So by comparing the resource fragments would be one way, but it seems awkward. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a json file for mapping between wordnet v3.0 and v3.1:
https://github.com/ozendelait/wordnet-to-json/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score -1):

A part of mappings could be found in the data set of this paper:

Learning Spatial Knowledge for Text to 3D Scene Generation, EMNLP 2014

The filename is shapenetsem.taxonomy.json